# Laravel GroupBy with Multiple Joins

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having problems with getting correct data in a three-way join.

**EDIT: Sample table structure**

```
Jobs Table

id | name     | country      | country_slug  | city

1  | Job1     | Canada       | canada        | Ontario

2  | Job2     | South Africa | south-africa  | Durban
```

```
Cheers Table

id |  rep  | jobs_id

1  |  14   | 2

2  |  9    | 1

3  |  12   | 2

4  |  23   | 1
```

```
Categories Table

id |  name  

1  |  PHP   

2  |  Laravel 

3  |  Javascript 

4  |  Go
```

```
category_job pivot Table

id |  category_id | job_id  

1  |  2           | 1

2  |  2           | 2

3  |  1           | 1

4  |  3           | 2

5  |  4           | 1
```

Here is an example of what my models look like:

```
Job

public function categories(){
   $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)
}


public function cheers(){
   $this->hasMany(Cheer::class)
}
```

```
Category

public function jobs() {
   $this->belongsToMany(Job::class)
}
```

```
Cheer

public function job() {
  return $this->belongsTo(Job::class);
}
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Group jobs by country
2. Get count of how many jobs are in each country (job_count)
3. Get count how many cities (distinct) in each group (city_count)
4. Sum (rep) in cheers relation table for each group
5. Get the most popular category for each country group via Categories relationship

**This is my code so far:**

```
      $result = Job::
            selectRaw(
            "jobs.country,
                            jobs.country_slug,
                            COUNT('jobs') as job_count,
                            COUNT(DISTINCT city) as city_count,
                            SUM(rep) as cheer_rep",
        )
            ->join('cheers', 'cheers.jobs_id', '=', 'jobs.id')
            ->orderByDesc('cheer_rep')
            ->groupBy('jobs.country', 'jobs.country_slug')
            ->get();
```

**Here are my problems;**

1. The job count is wrong because the join clause adds more results due to the hasMany relationship.
2. I can't seem to wrap my head around grouping the categories and getting the most occurring (popular) category.

```
Sample result
[
  {
    "country": "Canada",
    "country_slug": "canada",
    "job_count": 23,
    "cities": 5,
    "cheer_rep": "35000"
  },
  {
    "country": "South Africa",
    "country_slug": "south-africa",
    "job_count": 9,
    "cities": 2,
    "cheer_rep": "700"
  },
]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Also, if there's an eloquent way of achieving this, I'd appreciate that too.

Comment: First of all, your first problem is non existent, as you use `join` instead of `with` (for example). By using `join` you do not use the relationships defined in your models. Second of all, your `count('jobs')` statement is probably incorrect, as the way you have written in - it counts all of the rows no matter if any of the cells are `null`.

Comment: I added the models to explain what the relationships look like @KiprasT

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent way:

```
Job::with('cheers')
->select(DB::raw('count(country) as job_count, country'), 
         DB::raw('count(city) as city_count, city')
)
->orderByDesc('cheers.cheer_rep')
->groupBy('country', 'country_slug')
->get();
```

**Note: Not tested, as you did not provided DB schema.**

Comment: Hi, I just added sample table structure. This doesn't work as it says error: Unknown column  "cheers.cheer_rep"

Comment: you have cities in code and not in the job table, somehow you don't want to share the complete information, my solutions will keep giving you errors.

Comment: Added now. I missed it. I can't share the complete structure here because other fields are not relevant to my problem